# Limit of muscle atrophy

Tags: human-anatomy, neurophysiology, muscles

I read that lack of action leads to muscle atrophy , I experienced same when I had a cast for hand fracture. So how far this atrophy go, who decides minimum size of muscle due to lack of activity, for example in coma patients. 
Which part to brain or body signals muscle atrophy and upto what limit it should go?